# Merge 2 XML files with identical siblings using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have two XML files (XML1 and XML2: pasted below) and need to merge changes from XML2 to XML1 in to third file (say XML3) such that:

1) If same attribute found in both files then 
   1.a) Check if attibute values are different then overwrite value of XML1 with value from XML2. 
e.g. MasterControl is Enabled in XML1 while Disabled in XML2. 
After merge, expected output is MasterControl as Disabled in XML3.

1.b) If attribute values are same or empty in both file then no change in XML1 after merging in XML3.

2) If XML 1 has extra attributes which are not present in XML2 then add such attributes in merged file.

3) If XML 2 has extra attributes which are not present in  XML1 then add such attributes in merged file.

I have reffered  link "XSLT to Merge 2 XML Files" [XSLT to Merge 2 XML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665170/xslt-to-merge-2-xml-files), which solved most of the requirement excepts following:

After merging, i have faced issue in Rule ID tree where hierachy path is same for all Rule IDs. 
In above mentioned link, path is calculated for each element and based on it, merging done.

I am searching for generic solution because this is just small snippet of XML file. there are approx 300+ parameters in the files.
XML:1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="D:\test.xsl"?>
<NCP>
        <NCPList>
            <NCP ID="1" Label="LabelName">
                <ParametersList>
                <MasterControl>Enabled</MasterControl>              
                <ReservedPool></ReservedPool>               
                <Rule ID="1" Label="Label">
                    <RuleCriteria>
                        <CellType>Macro</CellType>
                    </RuleCriteria>                 
                    <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
                    <ReAssignment>Enabled</ReAssignment>                    
                </Rule> 

                <Rule ID="2" Label="Label">
                    <RuleCriteria>
                        <CellType>Micro</CellType>
                    </RuleCriteria>                 
                    <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
                    <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                </Rule>

                <Rule ID="3" Label="Label">
                    <RuleCriteria>
                        <CellType>Pico</CellType>
                    </RuleCriteria>                 
                    <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
                    <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                </Rule>             
            </ParametersList>
            </NCP>
        </NCPList>
    </NCP>
```

XMl2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="D:\test.xsl"?>
<NCP>
        <NCPList>
            <NCP ID="1" Label="LabelName">
                <ParametersList>
                <MasterControl>Disabled</MasterControl>             
                <ReservedPool></ReservedPool>               
                <Rule ID="1" Label="Label">
                    <RuleCriteria>
                        <CellType>Macro</CellType>
                    </RuleCriteria>                 
                    <Assignment>Disabled</Assignment>
                    <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                </Rule> 

                <Rule ID="2" Label="Label">
                    <RuleCriteria>
                        <CellType>Micro</CellType>
                    </RuleCriteria>                 
                    <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
                    <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                </Rule>

            </ParametersList>
            </NCP>
        </NCPList>
    </NCP>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:param name="aXmlPath" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="aDoc"     select="document('q_xml2.xml')" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- text nodes will be checked against doc A -->
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="calculatePath" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="valueFromA">
      <xsl:call-template name="nodeValueByPath">
        <xsl:with-param name="path"    select="$path" />
        <xsl:with-param name="context" select="$aDoc" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- either there is something at that path in doc A -->
      <xsl:when test="starts-with($valueFromA, 'found:')">
        <!-- remove prefix added in nodeValueByPath, see there --> 
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($valueFromA, 'found:')" />
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- or we take the value from doc B -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this calcluates a simpe path for a node -->
  <xsl:template name="calculatePath">
    <xsl:for-each select=".."> 
      <xsl:call-template name="calculatePath" />
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:if test="self::*">     
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '/')" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this retrieves a node value by its simple path -->
  <xsl:template name="nodeValueByPath">
    <xsl:param name="path"    select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="context" select="''" />

    <xsl:if test="contains($path, '/') and count($context)">
      <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="substring-before($path, '/')" />
      <xsl:variable name="nextPath" select="substring-after($path, '/')" />
      <xsl:variable name="currContext" select="$context/*[name() = $elemName][1]" />

      <xsl:if test="$currContext">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($nextPath, '/')">
            <xsl:call-template name="nodeValueByPath">
              <xsl:with-param name="path"    select="$nextPath" />
              <xsl:with-param name="context" select="$currContext" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="not($currContext/*)">
            <!-- always add a prefix so we can detect 
                 the case "exists in A, but is empty" -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('found:', $currContext/text())" />
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="D:\test.xsl"?>
<NCP>
            <NCPList>
                <NCP ID="1" Label="LabelName">
                    <ParametersList>
                    <MasterControl>Disabled</MasterControl>             
                    <ReservedPool/>             
                    <Rule ID="1" Label="Label">
                        <RuleCriteria>
                            <CellType>Macro</CellType>
                        </RuleCriteria>                 
                        <Assignment>Disabled</Assignment>
                        <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                    </Rule> 

                    <Rule ID="2" Label="Label">
                        <RuleCriteria>
                            <CellType>Macro</CellType>
                        </RuleCriteria>                 
                        <Assignment>Disabled</Assignment>
                        <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                    </Rule>

                    <Rule ID="3" Label="Label">
                        <RuleCriteria>
                            <CellType>Macro</CellType>
                        </RuleCriteria>                 
                        <Assignment>Disabled</Assignment>
                        <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                    </Rule>             
                </ParametersList>
                </NCP>
            </NCPList>
        </NCP>
```

see above ReservedPool attribute terminated without ending tag.
Also all Rule IDs merged with same CellType tree while both xmls have different CellType for each Rule Id .

Expected Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="D:\test.xsl"?>
<NCP>
            <NCPList>
                <NCP ID="1" Label="LabelName">
                    <ParametersList>
                    <MasterControl>Disabled</MasterControl>             
                    <ReservedPool></ReservedPool>               
                    <Rule ID="1" Label="Label">
                        <RuleCriteria>
                            <CellType>Macro</CellType>
                        </RuleCriteria>                 
                        <Assignment>Disabled</Assignment>
                        <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                    </Rule> 

                    <Rule ID="2" Label="Label">
                        <RuleCriteria>
                            <CellType>Micro</CellType>
                        </RuleCriteria>                 
                        <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
                        <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                    </Rule>

                    <Rule ID="3" Label="Label">
                        <RuleCriteria>
                            <CellType>Pico</CellType>
                        </RuleCriteria>                 
                        <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
                        <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>                   
                    </Rule>             
                </ParametersList>
                </NCP>
            </NCPList>
        </NCP>
```

Please provide help in above doubts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ReservedPool` in your example is not an attribute, and `<ReservedPool/>` is **exactly** the same thing as  `<ReservedPool></ReservedPool>`.

Comment: You should clarify one more thing: can you match the rules by their ID values? -- P.S. In XML, the word *attribute* has a very precise meaning; the things you want to merge are **not** attributes.

Comment: Rules can be matched with CellType "Macro" / "Micro"/ "Pico" etc. ID can be different for same CellType in both XMLs. Thanks for information. actually first time I am working with XML and XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespaces.

Edit first file:

```
<NCP xmlns="file/a">
```

Edit second file:

```
<NCP xmlns="file/b">
```

Define namespaces in xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f1="file/a" xmlns:f2="file/b">
```

Now you can select nodes and specify which namespace (and file accordingly) they belong to:

```
<xsl:variable name="rootFromFirstFile"    select="f1:NCP" />
```

Comment: thanks for response @Maxim Lazarev but I could not understand that how  will it resolve my problem mentioned above.  the expected output is updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

***Edited in response to your clarifications:***

I believe your requirements could be condensed to:

1. Take all parameters from XML1 that do **not** have a corresponding
   (overriding) parameter in XML2;
2. Take **all** parameters from XML2 (these are either overriding a
   parameter that exists in XML1, or extra parameters which are not
   present in XML1).

There's a further complication in that `Rules` need to be matched by their `CellType`, while other parameters (`MasterControl` and `ReservedPool`) by their name.

With that in mind, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="doc2" select="document('q_xml2.xml')" />

<xsl:variable name="doc2-param-names">
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc2/NCP/NCPList/NCP/ParametersList/*">
        <name><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></name>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="doc2-cell-types" select="$doc2/NCP/NCPList/NCP/ParametersList/Rule/RuleCriteria/CellType" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ParametersList"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- local parameters (other than Rules), with no external override -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Rule)] [not(name()=exsl:node-set($doc2-param-names)/name)]"/>
        <!-- local Rules, with no external override -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Rule[not(RuleCriteria/CellType=$doc2-cell-types)]"/>
        <!-- ALL external items -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc2/NCP/NCPList/NCP/ParametersList/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Testing with:

**XML INPUT**

```
<NCP>
  <NCPList>
    <NCP ID="1" Label="LabelName">
      <ParametersList>
        <MasterControl>Enabled</MasterControl>
        <ReservedPool/>
        <OLD>OLD</OLD>
        <Rule ID="1" Label="Label">
          <RuleCriteria>
            <CellType>Macro</CellType>
          </RuleCriteria>
          <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
          <ReAssignment>Enabled</ReAssignment>
        </Rule>
        <Rule ID="2" Label="Label">
          <RuleCriteria>
            <CellType>Micro</CellType>
          </RuleCriteria>
          <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
          <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>
        </Rule>
        <Rule ID="3" Label="Label">
          <RuleCriteria>
            <CellType>Pico</CellType>
          </RuleCriteria>
          <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
          <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>
        </Rule>
      </ParametersList>
    </NCP>
  </NCPList>
</NCP>
```

**File q_xml2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NCP>
  <NCPList>
    <NCP ID="1" Label="LabelName">
      <ParametersList>
        <MasterControl>DISABLED</MasterControl>
        <ReservedPool/>
        <NEW>NEW</NEW>
        <Rule ID="1" Label="Label">
          <RuleCriteria>
            <CellType>Macro</CellType>
          </RuleCriteria>
          <Assignment>Disabled</Assignment>
          <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>
        </Rule>
        <Rule ID="2" Label="Label">
          <RuleCriteria>
            <CellType>Micro</CellType>
          </RuleCriteria>
          <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
          <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>
        </Rule>
      </ParametersList>
    </NCP>
  </NCPList>
</NCP>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NCP>
   <NCPList>
      <NCP ID="1" Label="LabelName">
         <ParametersList>
            <OLD>OLD</OLD>
            <Rule ID="3" Label="Label">
               <RuleCriteria>
                  <CellType>Pico</CellType>
               </RuleCriteria>
               <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
               <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>
            </Rule>
            <MasterControl>DISABLED</MasterControl>
            <ReservedPool/>
            <NEW>NEW</NEW>
            <Rule ID="1" Label="Label">
               <RuleCriteria>
                  <CellType>Macro</CellType>
               </RuleCriteria>
               <Assignment>Disabled</Assignment>
               <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ID="2" Label="Label">
               <RuleCriteria>
                  <CellType>Micro</CellType>
               </RuleCriteria>
               <Assignment>Enabled</Assignment>
               <ReAssignment>Disabled</ReAssignment>
            </Rule>
         </ParametersList>
      </NCP>
   </NCPList>
</NCP>
```

Comment: michael - I have edited question with all requirements. Please check it again. i need to merge all attributes from XML2 to XML1.

Comment: I have tested with suggested XSLT but here problem is that only Rule Tree is getting merged.  <MasterControl> is not merged from XML2. In output file, MasterControl is Enabled while expected output is that it should be Disabled since same is mentioned in XML2.

Comment: @Rash10 My results are different. Which processor are you using?