# xslt 1.0 merge on key (special)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XSLT1.0: In have 2 XML files, the 1 first one being the "master"XML file. the 2nd one, only use the elements if they do not exist in the MASTER XML1. They should be matched on the bindings/binding/@name field. The 2nd XML file has bindings/binding/@name which is empty. This means that is should be merged with all bindings/binding/@name of the XML1 master document and also should be added separately. See the expected output for more details.

XML1 MASTER:

```
<bindings>
    <binding name="test1">
        <setting>
            <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
            <maxLogFileSize>20000</maxLogFileSize>
            <maxLogFileCount>5</maxLogFileCount>
            <threadCount>8001</threadCount>
            <NTService>
                <runAsNT>false</runAsNT>
                <startupType>automatic</startupType>
            </NTService>
            <java>
                <initHeapSize>64</initHeapSize>
                <maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>
                <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
            </java>
        </setting>  
    </binding>
    <binding name="test2">
        <setting>
            <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
            <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
            <maxLogFileSize>20000</maxLogFileSize>
            <maxLogFileCount>5</maxLogFileCount>
            <threadCount>435</threadCount>
            <NTService>
                <runAsNT>false</runAsNT>
                <startupType>automatic</startupType>
            </NTService>
            <java>
                <initHeapSize>64</initHeapSize>
                <maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>
                <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
            </java>
        </setting>  
    </binding>              
</bindings>
```

XML2 ONLY-IF-NOT-EXISTS:

```
<bindings>
    <binding name="">
        <machine>test-PC</machine>
        <product>
            <type>bwengine</type>
            <version/>
            <location/>
        </product>
        <description/>
        <contact>TEST</contact>
        <setting>
            <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
        </setting>                  
        <shutdown>
            <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
            <timeout>0</timeout>
        </shutdown>                 
    </binding>
    <binding name="test2">
        <setting>
            <startOnBoot>true</startOnBoot>
            <java>
                <otherMax>64</otherMax>
            </java>
        </setting>  
    </binding>                  
</bindings>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
<bindings>
    <binding name="test1">
        <machine>test-PC</machine>
        <product>
            <type>bwengine</type>
            <version/>
            <location/>
        </product>
        <description/>
        <contact>TEST</contact> 
        <setting>
            <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
            <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
            <maxLogFileSize>20000</maxLogFileSize>
            <maxLogFileCount>5</maxLogFileCount>
            <threadCount>8001</threadCount>
            <NTService>
                <runAsNT>false</runAsNT>
                <startupType>automatic</startupType>
            </NTService>
            <java>
                <initHeapSize>64</initHeapSize>
                <maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>
                <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
            </java>
        </setting>  
        <shutdown>
            <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
            <timeout>0</timeout>
        </shutdown>         
    </binding>
    <binding name="test2">
        <machine>test-PC</machine>
        <product>
            <type>bwengine</type>
            <version/>
            <location/>
        </product>
        <description/>
        <contact>TEST</contact> 
        <setting>
            <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
            <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
            <maxLogFileSize>20000</maxLogFileSize>
            <maxLogFileCount>5</maxLogFileCount>
            <threadCount>435</threadCount>
            <NTService>
                <runAsNT>false</runAsNT>
                <startupType>automatic</startupType>
            </NTService>
            <java>
                <initHeapSize>64</initHeapSize>
                <maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>
                <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
                <otherMax>64</otherMax>
            </java>
        </setting>  
        <shutdown>
            <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
            <timeout>0</timeout>
        </shutdown>         
    </binding>  
    <binding name="">
        <machine>test-PC</machine>
        <product>
            <type>bwengine</type>
            <version/>
            <location/>
        </product>
        <description/>
        <contact>ICT-O ESB Beheer</contact>
        <setting>
            <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
        </setting>                  
        <shutdown>
            <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
            <timeout>0</timeout>
        </shutdown>                 
    </binding>
    <binding name="test2">
        <setting>
            <startOnBoot>true</startOnBoot>
            <java>
                <otherMax>64</otherMax>
            </java>
        </setting>  
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Many similar questions about merging XML documents have already been answered. Do a search first, and if you then encounter a **specific** problem implementing one of the solutions, post your question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried searching. Can you link to the page where this question has been answered?

Comment: Try among these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3016153+[xslt]+merge

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT to Merge 2 XML Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665170/xslt-to-merge-2-xml-files)